WW II Film - Escaped prisoners capture a German Bunker
I want to find the title of the following film which I only saw once in about 1974. 
The film starts with I believe prisoners, possibly Italian or American being transported by truck in a German convoy. The prisoners escape and go up a hill to a German gun emplacement/ Bunker.  
They capture the Bunker and subsequently hold out against attacking German forces. The whole movie was focused on the Bunker/ Emplacement and efforts to repel the attacking forces
The film was dubbed in English and in Color. I couldn't swear to it being Italian but it had that sort of feel. The surrounding hillsides and ground looked barren
In the UK this was a Movie shown with the main feature being Fist of Fury. This was in the day when they used to put on two movies at the Cinema (Double Feature).

The date 1974 may not be accurate as the date the movie was made.

I think it is The Blockhouse (1973). Here is the plot from wikipedia:
On D-Day, a mixed group of forced labourers held by German forces take shelter from the bombardment inside a German bunker, but are then entombed when the entrances are blocked by shelling damage. By coincidence, the bunker is a storehouse, so the prisoners have enough food and wine to last them for years. However, they are trapped not for years but permanently, and the film analyzes how they deal with their underground prison, with their relationships, and with death.

Nice find but it doesn't quite seem to match the OP's description...still, it might be.

No I don't recall seeing this one, though it sounds good. At the time I didn't recognise the actors and I'm positive it was a European/ dubbed film. The people were not trapped inside and took advantage of the bunker/emplacement to fire on any soldiers advancing up the hill.
